# Не выходит подключить Sql Server к приложению Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql-server

Подключение через эмулятор срабатывает и приложение работает прекрасно, но когда я пытаюсь запустить приложение на телефоне ничего не получается. Приложение включается, очень долго грузится, но подключение не происходит.
Весь код подключения был взят с [этого сайта](https://programmerworld.co/android/how-to-connect-to-ms-sql-server-database-from-your-android-app-complete-steps/) Прикладываю основную часть кода:

Java:

```
private static String ip = "192.168.1.101";
private static String port = "1433";
private static String Classes = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
private static String database = "testDatabase";
private static String username = "test";
private static String password = "test";
private static String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+database;
private Connection connection = null;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        Class.forName(Classes);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        textView.setText("SUCCESS");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textView.setText("ERROR");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textView.setText("FAILURE");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
}
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: телефон находится в одной локальной сети с MS SQL Server'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Коннекшн надо "садить" в отдельный поток `AsyncTask` или `Runnable`
2. По-моему поддерживаются только JDBC драйвера Type 4

Comment: для обхода `NetworkOnMainThreadException` там используется хак с `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy`

Comment: Проблема в том, что подобная заглушка на `NetworkOnMainThreadException` не решает главную проблему. UI и обращение к коннекту продолжают душить друг-друга и как результат коннекшна то нет...

Comment: да, безусловно это проблема, но с учетом того что на эмуляторе приложение работает, я бы все таки сделал ставку на то, что телефон не находится в одной сети с сервером БД))

Comment: Ну да там адрес серый, так что вероятно...